# Postgres search column on the basis of data

Tags: postgresql

I have to search the column name on the basis of data.

My table

```
id | serv1 | serv2 | serv3 | serv4 | serv5 | serv6 |  
-------------------------------------------------------  
001| 2     | 3     | 5     | 1     | 4     | 6     |
-------------------------------------------------------  
002| 2     | 1     | 5     | 3     | 4     | 6     |
-------------------------------------------------------  
003| 6     | 2     | 5     | 3     | 4     | 1     |
```

I want the field name that have data value **1**.

**My output**

```
--------------
001| serv4    
--------------
002| serv2    
--------------
003| serv6   
--------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A case statement would do:

```
SELECT id,
       CASE WHEN serv1 = 1
            THEN 'serv1'
            WHEN serv2 = 1
            THEN 'serv2'
            WHEN serv3 = 1
            THEN 'serv3'
            WHEN serv4 = 1
            THEN 'serv4'
            WHEN serv5 = 1
            THEN 'serv5'
            WHEN serv6 = 1
            THEN 'serv6'
       END
FROM mytable;
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert the row to json, and use the function json_each_text to transpose. Then filter where the value equals `'1'`, note that json_each_text casts the value to text.

```
WITH mytable 
    (id, serv1, serv2, serv3, serv4, serv5, serv6) 
AS (
VALUES 
    ('001', 2,3,5,1,4,6),
    ('002', 2,1,5,3,4,6),
    ('003', 6,2,5,3,4,1)
)
SELECT id, tjs.key column_name
FROM mytable t, json_each_text(row_to_json(t)) tjs
WHERE tjs.value = '1'
```